# How to disable actions on a webpage for first mouse click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

On clicking any element on a web page (say links, button etc), I need to stop the action. However, if the user clicks on them again (on second click), the actions should happen and it should redirect to next page. 
I have this code to stop the action:

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

I need to write condition to check for mouse clicks. Please help.

UPDATE 1:

```
var count=0;
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("*");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
elements[i].addEventListener("click", nonJQuery, false);


var nonJQuery = function (event) {
//some code
count++;
if(count<2){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}
//some code
}
```

Thanks for the help. I'm writing something like this. I need to stop execution on all the elements on the web page and not on a particular element. So, my code looks like this.
If count is declared globally, and it is incremented in the function, next element I click will have wrong value. Can someone correct me?
P.S: Same if I use boolean as well.

Comment: Have you  included jQuery lib?

Comment: no..I'm including this piece of code in JavaFX application. It is a small part for the larger application. So, I'm not including Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `counter` for each element. You can use [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) attribute to store counter on the element itself.

```
$('mySelector').on('click', function(e) {
    // Get counter of this element
    var counter = parseInt($(this).data('clickCount'), 10) || 0;

    if (counter++ % 2 === 0) {
        // 
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    $(this).data('clickCount', counter);
});
```

**EDIT**

Without `jQuery`:

[`data docs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

```
element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // Get counter of this element
    var counter = parseInt((this.dataset.counter), 10) || 0;

    if (counter++ % 2 === 0) {
        // 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    this.dataset.counter = counter;
});
```

Comment: I like the use of data attribute! Nice one

Comment: Thanks. But can the same be written in javascript?

Comment: @Tushar, I have updated the question. The event listener is not on particular element. I have a problem setting the counter.

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj That's why you should use `this` to get/set the counter on the clicked element

Comment: Do I need to declare/initialize this.dataset.counter?

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj Not needed, as we're using `0` if not available

Comment: @NaveenBharadwaj Please create `jsfiddle`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81149/discussion-between-naveenbharadwaj-and-tushar).

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a counter and increase it at every click. The counter can be item specific or global depending on your requirement. Then you can check the counter value and have the conditional logic.

Comment: Correct. I'm new to javascript. I know the logic but don't know how to write code for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var inc = 0;
element.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  inc++;
  if(inc < 2){
   event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **boolean** variable. Do:

```
var check= true;
element.addEventListener('click',function(event){
  if(check){
   check= false;
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();
  }else{// do your task

}
});
```

Comment: Event listener is on all the elements in the web page and not on particular element.

Comment: In that case you may do as tushar said, in that too you may use boolean.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/turutosiya/kLausy7x/1/

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Click Here 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Click Here 2</a></li>    
    <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Click Here 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Click Here 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
(function(){
    $(function(){
        $('a').on('click', function(event){
            if(!$(this).data('clicked')) {
                $(this).data('clicked', true);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });   
    });
})();
```